# Passing variables to a YAML array which is being imported from routing_dev.yml

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on the Synfony framework And I am Fresher in Synfony

Framework. I face a problem When I want to run my function I got one error.

Here is my controller:-

```
<?php 

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/blog")
     */
    public function showAction()
    {
      echo "hello friend";
    }
}
?>
```

my routing.yml file is:-

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation    
blog_data:
path:   /blog
defaults: {_controller: AppBundle:blog:show }
```

Here I created the blog_data my self and I did not mention it any where because i don't know where it is declare.

my routing.dev.yml file is:-

_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_errors:
    resource: "@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml"
    prefix:   /_error

_main:
    resource: routing.yml

when I hit URL:-

**http://localhost/mysymfony/web/app_dev.php/blog**

I got the error

**The definition of "blog_data" in "C:\xampp\htdocs\mysymfony\app/config\routing.yml" must be a YAML array in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysymfony\app/config\routing.yml (which is being imported from "C:\xampp\htdocs\mysymfony\app/config/routing_dev.yml").**

How to resolved this problem.

Comment: seems you are missing spaces before `path` and `defaults` definitions

Comment: No,  I am sure that  i am not missing spaces before path and defaults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your routing.yml file only needs to contain this:

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

Try that and see if it works. Let us know the result.

Answer (score 0):

Make 4 spaces before path and defaults.

```
blog_data:
    path: /blog
    defaults: {_controller: AppBundle:blog:show }
```